# How do I click dropdown arrow in Facebook programmatically with VB.NET?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to programmatically click the drop-down arrow that appears when we open a specific FB post such as https://www.facebook.com/userxxx/posts/10155300116786742

Can anyone please provide me the code for Visual Basic? Thank you.

[Drop-down arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wQ1T.png)

Comment: I dont think there's enough info in this question to help you. Is the VB application running some sort of web browser control ? or is the vb application running in a computer that has a browser open? If the latter, I would use some javascript thingy to do it.... not a vb exe

Comment: Hi, my VB app has a browser control. If clicking the drop-down arrow in browser control is not possible, can you provide me the JavaScript solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your webbrowser control you can invoke javascript code inside of the requested page by using

```
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", "some javascrtip here")
```

that leaves us with the problem of doing the dropdown click with javascript. That you can do with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-testid=post_chevron_button]")[0].click()
```

so, all together it end up being

```
Dim micode As Object() = {"document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid=post_chevron_button]')[0].click()
"}
WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", micode)
```

notice the js code provided might change. You should decide what code is better yourself. I recommend open facebook or any page, in chrome and press F12 ... that is the developer console. You can run and debug javascript there.... have fun!

Comment: Oh my God, I can't believe your code runs perfect!!!!!!!!!!! You have no idea I spent several days searching for this but couldn't come across a soln. You helped me in just a few minutes. Thank you so much from the bottom of my heart. How do I upvote your answer? Sorry, I'm new here. Thank you so much again!!!!!!!!!!! I'm greatful.